# firestore doesn't work in the emulator in cloud function tutorial

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, wsl-2

I followed the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started (twice from scratch) and the firestore is blank.

Note, in step 3.3 where i needed o initialize the firestore, i followed the steps in the console and initialized it on the web

The Log from firebase emulator suite `http://localhost:4000/logs`

```
12:19:34 I ui Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log 12:19:35 I functions Watching "/home/kirill/try-function-d8787/functions" for Cloud Functions... 
12:19:36 I functions http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/try-function-d8787/us-central1/addMessage). 
12:19:36 I functions firestore function initialized. 12:19:36 I

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4000 │ 
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐ 
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │ 
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │ 
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │ 
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘   

Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the*-debug.log files.   

12:22:34 I function[addMessage] Beginning execution of "addMessage" 
12:22:35 I function[addMessage] Finished "addMessage" in ~1s 
12:22:35 I function[makeUppercase] Beginning execution of "makeUppercase" 
12:22:36 I function[makeUppercase] {   "severity": "INFO",   "message": "Uppercasing Md0HKOGNHNVo7pk9hhbq uppercaseme" } 
12:22:36 I function[makeUppercase] Finished "makeUppercase" in ~1s
```

firestore tab:

[image]

terminal log (not sure how to post it properly):

```
    ~ ❯❯❯ cd try-function-d8787 ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ firebase login Already logged in as kirill.igum@gmail.com ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ firebase init firestore
            ✘ 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########                                                                                                                              ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##                                                                                                                                    ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######                                                                                                                                ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##                                                                                                                                    ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########
    
    You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
    
      /home/kirill/try-function-d8787
    
    
    === Project Setup
                                                                                                                                                                                                        First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project. You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, but for now we'll just set up a default project.
    
    ? Please select an option: Use an existing project                     ? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: try-function-d8787 (try-function)                                      i  Using project try-function-d8787 (try-function)
                                                                                                                                                                                                        === Firestore Setup
                                                                                                                                                                                                        Firestore Security Rules allow you to define how and when to allow     requests. You can keep these rules in your project directory           and publish them with firebase deploy.
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ? What file should be used for Firestore Rules? firestore.rules        Firestore indexes allow you to perform complex queries while           maintaining performance that scales with the size of the result        set. You can keep index definitions in your project directory          and publish them with firebase deploy.                                 ? What file should be used for Firestore indexes? firestore.indexes.json                                                 i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...                      i  Writing project information to .firebaserc... i  Writing gitignore file to .gitignore...
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔  Firebase initialization complete! ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ firebase init functions
                                                                                                                                                                                                  [3/87]     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###    
    ######  ########                                                                                                                              ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##                                                                                                                                    ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######                                                                                                                                ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##                                                                                                                                    ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########
    
    You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
    
      /home/kirill/try-function-d8787
    
    Before we get started, keep in mind:
    
      * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory
    
    
    === Project Setup
    
    First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project. You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, but for now we'll just set up a default project.
    
    i  .firebaserc already has a default project, using try-function-d8787.
    
    === Functions Setup
    
    A functions directory will be created in your project with a Node.js   package pre-configured. Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy.
    
    ? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript                                                             ? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes                                                                    ✔  Wrote functions/package.json ✔  Wrote functions/.eslintrc.json ✔  Wrote functions/index.js ✔  Wrote functions/.gitignore ? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
    
    > protobufjs@6.10.1 postinstall /home/kirill/try-function-d8787/functions/node_modules/protobufjs     
    > node scripts/postinstall
    
    npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.                                                             added 360 packages from 263 contributors and audited 360 packages in
    11.852s
    
    34 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
    
    found 0 vulnerabilities
    
    
    i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json... i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...
    
    ✔  Firebase initialization complete! ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ ls functions  firebase.json  firestore.indexes.json  firestore.rules      ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ cd functions ~/t/functions ❯❯❯ vim index.js ~/t/functions ❯❯❯ cd .. ~/try-function-d8787 ❯❯❯ firebase emulators:start i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore ⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, pubsub ✔  functions: Using node@10 from host. i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log                      i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log i  functions: Watching "/home/kirill/try-function-d8787/functions" for Cloud Functions...     ✔  functions[addMessage]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/try-function-d8787/us-central1/addMessage). ✔  functions[makeUppercase]: firestore function initialized.
    
    ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4000 │                                                └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    
    ┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐       │ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │       ├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤       │ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │       ├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤       │ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │       └───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘       Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500
    
    Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the
    *-debug.log files.
    
    i  functions: Beginning execution of "addMessage" i  functions: Finished "addMessage" in ~1s i  functions: Beginning execution of "makeUppercase"
    >  {"severity":"INFO","message":"Uppercasing Md0HKOGNHNVo7pk9hhbq uppercaseme"}                                                          i  functions: Finished "makeUppercase" in ~1s
```

Comment: I have went trough this tutorial and everything is working fine. What browser and os you are facing this?

Comment: @vitooh Google Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). Ubuntu 20.04 on wsl 2

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any Windows machine to try this. However, if I understand correctly you started emulator inside the WSL and you are trying to reach it from Windows... ?

Comment: Emulators always start off empty, unless you're explicitly loading in data. Have you written any code to add data to it?

Comment: @vitooh yes, the log works fine. without the emulator (deploy), things work fine too.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman the tutorial script has to write lower case and upper case message to the firestore in the emulator

Comment: @kirill_igum but you are getting to emulator GUI from Windows not inside WSL?

Comment: @vitooh correct. i launched the emulator inside WSL and opened chrome from windows

Comment: I am not able to run WSL anywere, however the same behavior you may find running emulator in cloud shell and opening GUI in cloud shell preview. I suggest to raise the case to Firebase support: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs

Answer (score -1):

Firebase emulator doesn't work on WSL2 [right now](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2334). I solved this by using git-bash console with a windows installation of nodejs/npm